# I deleted an account off of a website and it still shows up in Google searches?

Tags: google-search

Well pretty much I had two accounts that I **really** wanted to delete from 2 websites because they were embarrassing . I deleted both of them but whenever I search my name up on Google both of the accounts show up!

I tried to log back into them so I could report it and I already know one of the sites said that they have no control over what search engines do, but the other one won't let me log back in to send a complaint. How do I permanently delete these from Google's or any other search engine?

Comment: May be helpful: http://lifehacker.com/5850288/how-to-fix-internet-embarrassments-and-improve-your-online-reputation http://lifehacker.com/5963864/how-to-clean-up-your-online-presence-and-make-a-great-first-impression

Answer (score 3):

It takes time. They don't crawl every site every second. You can never be sure when it will happen, but it will.

One way is to keep updating the parts of the site that are good, over time these will overwhelm the parts you want them to forget.

Answer (score 1):

These should eventually automatically fall out of search results. If you're a bit more anxious, Google have a process to [remove content from someone else's site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663688).

You probably want to use the "Remove content that’s not live" option. There's no *guarantee* this will actually get the results removed any quicker than waiting (or at all in some cases), but will probably help speed the process along.